# extracting url ending in .pdf from a list of html nodes in R

Tags: r, html-parsing

I have a list of urls that each contain a url leading to a pdf document. I would like to extract and download the pdf document using R. Here is my code up until now:

Downloading the data from reliefweb.int

```
#get all the results for the Afghanistan HNO search
result <- GET("https://api.reliefweb.int/v1/reports?appname=rwint-user-0&profile=list&preset=latest&slim=1&query[value]=(primary_country.iso3%3A%22afg%22)%20AND%20ocha_product%3A%22Humanitarian%20Needs%20Overview%22%20AND%20source%3A%22UN%20Office%20for%20the%20Coordination%20of%20Humanitarian%20Affairs%22&query[operator]=AND")

#create a list of all the urls listed in the search page
rawToChar(result$content)
result2<- fromJSON(rawToChar(result$content))
urllist<- result2[["data"]][["fields"]][["url"]]

#Extraxt links to the pdf docs
urlpdf<- lapply(urllist,read_html)
```

With this code I have a list of html nodes but I am stuck on how to extract the .pdf urls from that. Any idea how I could proceed or if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `rvest`, so you can do:

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

result2<- fromJSON(rawToChar(result$content))
urllist<- result2[["data"]][["fields"]][["url"]]

urlpdf<- lapply(urllist, read_html)

links <- lapply(urlpdf, function(x) html_attr(html_nodes(x, xpath = "//a"), "href"))

pdfs <- lapply(links, function(x) grep("\\.pdf$", x, value = TRUE))
```

Which results in:

```r
pdfs
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/afg_humanitarian_needs_overview_2020.pdf"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/afg_2019_humanitarian_needs_overview.pdf"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/afg_2018_humanitarian_needs_overview_1.pdf"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/afg_2017_hno_english.pdf"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/afg_2016_hno_final_20151209.pdf"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/Afghanistan%20HRP%202015%20HNO%20Final%2023Nov2014%20%281%29.pdf"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "https://afg.humanitarianresponse.info/system/files/documents/files/Afg_2014HNO_FINALv2_0.pdf"
#> [2] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/Afg_2014HNO_FINALv2_0.pdf"
```